# ATT00006.dat file autmatically attached in mail attachment

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, email-attachments

I have a page that have fileupload control, on the submission of the form, when the fileupload control has file, file is sent via attachment in a mail and working absulutly fine, but when the fileupload control does not have file, **ATT00006.dat** file is automatically sent via email attachment.

Reference URL: http://nextech.pk/Enquiry.aspx?Enq=cu

Advance Thanks for any help

**Edit -- Code:**

```
 hpf = fup1.PostedFile;
    String toEmail = "test@hotmail.com";
    String fromEmail = "mailer@hotmail.com";
    MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail);
    objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    StringBuilder MailBody = new StringBuilder();

    MailBody.Append("<html><head></head><body> <br>");
    MailBody.Append("<br>" + "An enquiry is filed <br><br>");
    MailBody.Append("<strong><u>Enquirer Information</u></strong>" + "<br><br>");
    MailBody.Append("<strong>Contact Name:</strong>&#09;" + txtFirstName.Text + "<br>");
    MailBody.Append("<strong>Email:</strong>&#09;&#09;&#09; " + txtEmail.Text + "<br>");
    MailBody.Append("<strong>Institute:</strong>&#09;&#09; " + txtInstitute.Text + "<br>");
    MailBody.Append("<strong>Phone #:</strong>&#09;&#09; " + txtPhone.Text + "<br>");

    MailBody.Append("<br><strong>Description:</strong><br>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; " + txtEnquiry.Text + "<br>");

    if (hpf != null)
    {
        MailBody.Append("<br>" + "This email also contains an attachment:- <Strong>(" + hpf.FileName + ")</Strong><br>");
    }

    MailBody.Append("</body></html>");
    objMail.Body = MailBody.ToString();
    if (hpf != null)
    {
        System.IO.Stream inputStream = hpf.InputStream;
        String fileName = hpf.FileName;
        Attachment attach = new Attachment(inputStream, fileName);

        objMail.Attachments.Add(attach);
    }
    SmtpClient SmtpClnt = new SmtpClient();
    SmtpClnt.Send(objMail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a mis-match in the attachment type that the system doesn't understand. Please post your code and what you do when there is not file as an attachment.

Comment: When there is not file attached. Do you see the text "This email also contains an attachment " text along with the ATT00006.dat attachment.

Comment: if user upload file, then it is like... This email also contains an attachment:- (uploaded file name)

Comment: I asked when there is no attachment then do you see the line which says "the email also contains .... ".... i.e do you see it everytime or only when there is atttchment?

Comment: every time i am seeing in the email

Comment: ok. the instead of using if (hpf != null) . Try using if (fup1.HasFile) and see whether it works.

Comment: yes, I already have assumed same and have tested it on live server

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you ever got an answer to this, but I've recently studied the problem in detail.  The problem occurs because you did not provide an explicit name for the attachment.  ASP.NET will always attach as .DAT unless the name is explicitly defined.

The problem is that people assume ASP.NET will use the Filename as the attachment name, which doesn't happen!

In your code, you should create an instance of the attachment, then provide the name explicitly using the FileUpload.FileName property:

```
Dim att As New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fu.PostedFile.InputStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet) ' use Octet for binary files '
att.Name = fu.FileName ' get the file name and type automatically '
mm.Attachments.Add(att)
```

A full explanation [of ASP.NET attaching .DAT files is available here](http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/ASPNET_Net_Mail_attaches_DAT_files_to_emails)

Comment: This should be the actual answer, thanks for your input mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the mail server you are using (or antivirus software used by the mail server) is automatically adding this file.

Does the file in question contain anything, or is it empty?

Comment: but when we attach file, then this ATT00006.dat is not attached in email?

Comment: what does mean check this URL http://nextech.pk/Enquiry.aspx?Enq=cu if user upload file in fileupload control then file will be attached otherwise empty

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is does the file ATT00006.dat have any contents?

Comment: its 121 bytes and I have try to open it and it is not opened, but I don't think this file contain something

Comment: If the file is 121 bytes, then it must contain *something* :)

Try opening it in notepad to see what it contains

Comment: Its empty, I have open in notepad